# How to do push notification in Ionic 7 PWA with Firebase

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, ionic7

How to do push notification in Ionic v7 pwa with Firebase

I converted the Ionic app to PWA but due to standalone components i'm facing problems making push-notification please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great [guide](https://capawesome.io/blog/the-push-notifications-guide-for-capacitor/) to get push notifications working on any platform.